# Enum a record in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a record that contains a bunch of pointers that I would like to free.

```
type 
 FreeStruct = record
 Addr1 : Pointer;
 Addr2 : Pointer;
 Addr3 : Pointer;
 // ....
end;
```

So I would like to do something like:

```
var
 MyStruct : FreeStruct:
begin
 //MyStruct.Addr1 := ...;
 for i := 0 to NumberOfFieldsInRecord do begin
  VirtualFree (ValueOfFieldNumberOfMyStruct[I],0, MEM_RELEASE);
 end;
end;
```

I heard there is something like RTII but I don't know how to use it properly with records and Delphi 7.

Comment: Why not to use for instance `array[0..n] of Pointer` instead ?

Comment: Cause I might have more and/or different types of vars in that Record later. I also need a struct since it's easier to handle.

Comment: Well, then wrap that array into record, ie `type 
 FreeStruct = record Addr: array[0..n] of Pointer; {other fields} end`

Comment: I also tried this but I have no idea how this is suppose to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096120/enum-const-record-fields

Comment: It works by dint of being compiled by a modern compiler. You are using an ancient compiler that is over 10 years old. And so you are missing RTTI.

Comment: If you had Delphi-2006 or newer, it would be possible to add a method `Clear` in the record, that would take care of freeing the pointers. See [`"Advanced Record Structure Type in Turbo Delphi and Delphi 2006"`](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2006/qt/newdelphirecord.htm).

Comment: @LURD That doesn't really help much. You can just have a procedure named `ClearMyRecord` that takes the record as a `var` parameter. The code gen is probably identical. You are no nearer enumerating the fields.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, a procedure or a method is fine. My point is to write code so it can be reused and to avoid DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Rtti solution for your Delphi-7 version.

If you don't want to implement @ain's suggestion with an array of pointers inside a record,
here is a suggestion that uses a [`variant part in the record`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records) to accomplish a similar thing.
You can freely use `myStruct.AddrX` names for clarity in code, but also `myStruct.allAddresses[X-1]` to address the same field.

```
Type
  FreeStruct = 
    record          
      intExample : Integer;  // not in the variant part

      case boolean of // Variant structure where the different parts overlap in memory
      true : ( Addr1 : Pointer;
               Addr2 : Pointer;
               Addr3 : Pointer);
      false : (allAddresses : array[0..2] of Pointer);          
    end;

procedure ClearFreeStruct( var AStruct : FreeStruct);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(AStruct.allAddresses) do 
  begin
    // Dispose of allocated pointers
  end;
end;
```

You can expand the structure with more pointers, but also include other fields (before the variant part).

---

It is possible to use an array of pointers within your record without giving up clarity.
By using an `enumeration`, it is possible to address each pointer with a relevant name.

> Example: myStruct.Addr[peAddr1]

```
Type
  PointerEnum = (peAddr1,peAddr2,peAddr3);

  FreeStruct =
    record
      intExample : Integer;

      Addr : array[PointerEnum] of Pointer;
    end;

procedure ClearFreeStruct( var AStruct : FreeStruct);
var
  pe : PointerEnum;
begin
  for pe := Low(PointerEnum) to High(PointerEnum) do
  begin
    // Dispose(AStruct.Addr[pe]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! This does the job just fine. A little bit more complicated than I expected but it works.

Comment: Benjamin, am I guessing right assuming the struct field names is the reason for not using an array of pointers straight off? In that case I may post an alternate solution that is simpler and equally clear.

Comment: The 2nd Edit you made is clearer. That is a really easy way to enum the array(?!). I just wanted a solution that doesn't make write too much code and call the same function over and over again just because I add something new to a struct.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware there are no methods to support record field iteration.
You can however play with the record structure on a low level basis (look here: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/18/295611.html)

Maybe you are better off restructuring your code so you will not need records for pointer storage.

Comment: I might just end up adding the first field with an integer, that contains the count of the fields and then calculate every 4 bytes. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Rtti for record field iteration came in Delphi-2010.